# Set projection with GDAL and Python of a raster file

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal

I have the following script that allows masking pixels below a certain threshold for all TIFF files in a directory; the user should specify the path, the threshold, and the bund number. The output file should have the same projection as the input file, but this is not working and the output file does not have any projection. I am using these lines:

```
# Set the projection and geotransform
output_dataset.SetProjection(dataset.GetProjection())
output_dataset.SetGeoTransform(dataset.GetGeoTransform())
```

The full script looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal
import argparse
import os

def maskPixels(input_tif_dir, band_idx, thr):
    # Get a list of all tif files in the input folder
    tif_files = [f for f in os.listdir(input_tif_dir) if f.endswith('.tif')]
    band_idx = int(band_idx)

    # Loop through each tif file
    for tif_file in tif_files:
        # Open the raster file
        dataset = gdal.Open(os.path.join(input_tif_dir, tif_file), gdal.GA_Update)

        # Read the threshold band into numpy array
        threshold_band = dataset.GetRasterBand(band_idx)
        threshold = threshold_band.ReadAsArray().astype(np.float32)
        thr_str = str(thr).split('.', 1)[1]

        # Get the number of bands in the raster
        num_bands = dataset.RasterCount

        # Loop through each band
        for band_idx in range(1, num_bands + 1):
            thr = float(thr)
            print(thr)
            # Read the raster band into numpy array
            band = dataset.GetRasterBand(band_idx)
            array_to_mask = band.ReadAsArray().astype(np.float32)

            # Apply the threshold to the array
            array_to_mask[threshold > thr] = 0

            # Create a new raster file for the masked band
            driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
            output_path = os.path.join(input_tif_dir, 'thr_lt' + thr_str + '_' + tif_file)
            output_dataset = driver.Create(output_path, dataset.RasterXSize, dataset.RasterYSize, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)

            # Set the projection and geotransform
            output_dataset.SetProjection(dataset.GetProjection())
            output_dataset.SetGeoTransform(dataset.GetGeoTransform())

            # Write the masked band to the output raster file
            output_band = output_dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
            output_band.WriteArray(array_to_mask)
            output_band.SetNoDataValue(0)

            # Save and close the output dataset
            output_dataset = None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    aparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='....'

    )
    aparser.add_argument(
        '--input-tif-dir',
        default=None
    )

    aparser.add_argument(
        '--band-idx',
        default=None
    )

    aparser.add_argument(
        '--thr',
        default=None
    )

    args = aparser.parse_args()
    maskPixels(args.input_tif_dir, args.band_idx, args.thr)
```

When I run the script, I get this error:

> ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: SQLite error on SELECT name,
> type, coordinate_system_auth_name, coordinate_system_code,
> datum_auth_name, datum_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code,
> text_definition, deprecated FROM geodetic_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND
> code = ?: no such column: area_of_use_auth_name

Comment: You have mismatched proj library and proj.db. How did you install gdal?

Comment: @user2856, I think I did it using Anaconda as follows: conda install -c conda-forge gdal

Comment: I'm curious; I don't have any problem with the projection when I execute the script from the Anaconda prompt. The issue arises when I execute it from the Anaconda Powershell prompt.

Comment: Can you run `conda init powershell` in the Anaconda Powershell prompt? If that fails (possibly with an error like "`WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system`"), you may be blocked from running powershell scripts and need to run `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser`. If that fails, you're probably in a locked down corporate environment and there's not much you can do.

Comment: I mention this because GDAL needs the environment variable "`GDAL_DATA`" set properly to find the correct proj.db file. When activating a conda environment in powershell, the `{path to your env}\etc\conda\activate.d\gdal-activate.ps1`"  should be run automatically by conda which sets this variable.  If running scripts in powershell is blocked, then the environment won't be activated correctly and this variable won't be set. The command prompt doesn't have this script blocking restriction so the activation of the conda environment works as expected.